# Spring Keycloak cannot use HTTPS_PROXY

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I have problem with using `keycloak` integration through `HTTP_PROXY`.

My `keycloak` config is as follows:

```
# Keycloak
keycloak.realm                      = ${KEYCLOAK_REALM:}
keycloak.auth-server-url            = ${KEYCLOAK_URL:}
keycloak.ssl-required               = ${KEYCLOAK_SSL:external}
keycloak.resource                   = ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID:}
keycloak.credentials.secret         = ${KEYCLOAK_SECRET:}
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = false
keycloak.bearer-only                = false
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=${KEYCLOAK_AUTH_ROLE:USER}
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/v2/auth/keycloak
```

With all variables set properly. While trying to use login function (when entering to `/v2/auth/keycloak`) I get:

`Connection timeout: https://$KEYCLOAK_URL/auth/realms/$KEYCLOAK_REALM/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Which means that `keycloak` doesn't use provided proxy. What I tried:

- setting env variables: `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` (both upper case and lowercase)
- Setting env variable: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true"`

None of those work, in proxy log I don't see any try to reach `.well-known` endpoint.

Can anyone please give me a hint how to force `spring-keycloak` to use given system proxy?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs here : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_java_adapter_config

You should be aple to use proxy-url in your adapter configuration :

```
# Keycloak
keycloak.realm                      = ${KEYCLOAK_REALM:}
keycloak.auth-server-url            = ${KEYCLOAK_URL:}
keycloak.ssl-required               = ${KEYCLOAK_SSL:external}
keycloak.resource                   = ${KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID:}
keycloak.credentials.secret         = ${KEYCLOAK_SECRET:}
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = false
keycloak.bearer-only                = false
keycloak.proxy-url                  = http://username:password@your_proxy:port
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=${KEYCLOAK_AUTH_ROLE:USER}
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/v2/auth/keycloak
```